# What is this Minecraft mod that helps you teleport to places quickly with "waypoints"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, mod-identification

What is this mod called? Both syndicate and the diamond minecart.

It is a mod that helps you teleport to places quickly with "waypoints".

The menu looks like this:
[image: screenshot of mod]

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted, "what is this mod called (that i saw someone use)" sounds like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @kutschkem but a quarter of the question isn't coherent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This mod is called [VoxelMap](http://www.minecraftmods.com/voxelmap/). In addition to adding waypoints, it also adds a minimap to the top right corner of the screen, including a radar of mobs (all configurable).

Answer (score 2):

This mod call [VoxelMap Mod](http://file-minecraft.com/voxelmap-mod/), VoxelMap was originally Zan’s minimap, a rather famous minimap mod created by Zaneris.

Mod Installation:

Download and run the latest version of [Minecraft Forge 1.11.2](http://file-minecraft.com/minecraft-forge-api-minecraft/) (For 1.11 or older) or [LiteLoader] (For 1.7.10)

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is Voxelmap but these days it requires lightloader or something.